How to call Java code Activity from Kotlin compose Activity
How to call Java code Activity from Kotlin compose Activity.
There are a lot of post to the other way(Call Kotlin from Java) but seems it does not apply to my case because it gives (this@MainActivity unresolved reference).
I created Java Activities using the Android Studio templates and they work successfully but I created one manually and that one does not work using the same code to call the other template Activity.
Strangely, instead of giving a runtime error it brings another Activity with a completely different name.
I am providing some code but if you need more to be able to help please advice.
This is the code to call the Activity:
Button(
    onClick = {
        Log.d("basic activity", "calling")
        val intent = Intent(mContext, BasicMainActivity::class.java)
        //gdriveCallAct.launch(intent)
        mContext.startActivity(intent)

    }
) {
    Text(text = "Basic Activity")
}

This is calling the manually created Java Activity:
Button(
    onClick = {
        Log.d("cloud activity", "calling")
        val intent = Intent(mContext, CloudMainActivity::class.java)
        //gdriveCallAct.launch(intent)
        mContext.startActivity(intent)

    }
) {
    Text(text = "Backup To Cloud")
}

This is the merged Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mastering.houseinventory"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="26"
        android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- Include required permissions for Google Maps API to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <queries>

        <!-- Needs to be explicitly declared on Android R+ -->
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
    </queries>

    <permission
        android:name="com.mastering.houseinventory.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.mastering.houseinventory.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mastering.houseinventory.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mastering.cloud.EmptyMainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mastering.cloud.CloudMainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mastering.mylibrary.BasicMainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mastering.pdfactivity.PdfMainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mastering.houseinventory.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path_provider" />
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.room.MultiInstanceInvalidationService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.mastering.cloud.ListActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.karumi.dexter.DexterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Dexter.Internal.Theme.Transparent" />
        <activity
            android:name="pub.devrel.easypermissions.AppSettingsDialogHolderActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/EasyPermissions.Transparent" /> <!-- Needs to be explicitly declared on P+ -->
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
            Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION"
            android:visibleToInstantApps="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="androidx.compose.ui.tooling.PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mastering.houseinventory.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.DUMP" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.INSTALL_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SKIP_FILE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SAVE_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.BENCHMARK_OPERATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

This error occurs when the failed Activity is called:
Failed to deliver inset control state change to w=Window{84c245d u0 com.mastering.houseinventory/com.mastering.cloud.CloudMainActivity}
android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
    at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:479)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3802)
    at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$3(InsetsStateController.java:343)
    at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.$r8$lambda$8yykPRG1GyNq_J17QvL9d5xANMc(InsetsStateController.java:0)
    at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:294)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate(WindowAnimator.java:202)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$new$1(WindowAnimator.java:99)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.$r8$lambda$aHNu1uhcqxihX5NZc4McDDQPAyw(WindowAnimator.java:0)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.doFrame(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:878)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)


What does "it brings another Activity with a completely different name." mean?

I have other Activities in my project. There is one called PDFMainActivity. When I call the one I want called CloudMainActivity instead it shows the PDFMainActivity.  You can see the Log Cat lines I posted it does try to start CloudMainActivity but fails..

You're getting a DeadObjectException, so maybe try one of the suggested solutions for that, like this one.

I don't fill that link address my case. The Activity I am calling is not hosted elsewhere, is a module in the same application. It just opens a screen with some Buttons that will execute some java code..

I never found a way to identify the cause of the problem so I could not fix it. I converted the code from Java to Kotlin and moved the Activity as a branch of the Main package  instead of a module. I am not happy about that because I could not learn a better coding.
